# OnActivityResult get null as the intent passed even though I sent an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I have two activities. The second activity is called from the first using `startActivityForResult(intent,request_code)`.
In the second activity I have this code:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
i.putExtra("data" , some data);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,i);
finish();
```

Then, to get the data in the first activity I use this code:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent intent)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode==this.uploadRequestCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        data = intent.get("data")
    }
```

I start the activity this way:

```
Intent uploadIntent = new Intent(this,uploadActivity.class)
startActivityForResult(uploadIntent,this.uploadRequestCode)
```

The problem is that the result code I get is RESULT_CANCELLED even though I set RESULT_OK.

**NOTE**

**I am not talking about a situation when back button is pressed.**

**UPDATE**

I found out that the intent I get in onActivityResult() is null even though I sent an intent, that's why the result code was RESULT_CANCELLED.

Anyone knows why the intent is null?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can help you out, something from a project that I have

This how I do start my activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, ActivityThatReturnInfo.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

This is from the activity that I want to return some value

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("VAR",someInfo);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

This is on the activity that as started the one that is waiting for the information

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case 1:
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                String result = data.getStringExtra("VAR");
                // Code to do
            }
            break;
        default:
            IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(result != null)
            {
                if(result.getContents() != null)
                {
                    // Code to do
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but that's not answering my question. My problem was that the result code is CANCELLED even though I sent OK. Means, it doesn't get inside the if condition

Comment: Ohh sry, try to do what ss_ told on is anwser, replace the `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,i);` with `setResult(RESULT_OK,i);` if that doesn't work, I don't know the default value for the `Activity.RESULT_OK` but just in case do a log of the `resultCode` to see if comes as correct

Comment: I tried sending RESULT_OK, Activity.RESULT_OK and -1 which is the value of RESULT_OK. Still doesn't work

Comment: Strange, did you checked the `requestCode` if its the one that `this.uploadRequestCode` has? Since both must be true to enter in the `if` maybe the problem comes from it.

Comment: yes I checked both values and the problem is with the result code

Comment: I know that sounds silly, but if you all rdy have done `setResult(-1,intent);` and the default value of `Activity.RESULT_OK` is -1 then the `Activity.RESULT_OK` can't be -1 also there, on the if try to put like this `if (requestCode== 100 && resultCode == 1)` start the activity as `startActivityForResult(i, 100);` and before finish change to `setResult(1,i);`

Comment: RESULT_OK is really -1 but I got RESULT_CANCELLED because the intent passed was null. Do you know what could have caused this problem?

Comment: From what I have understood what is null is this `this.uploadRequestCode` ? if yes, try put the raw value of `request_code` in `startActivityForResult(intent,request_code)`, put the value not the variable to see if still comes null or not

Comment: that's not the problem, `this.uploadRequestCode` is not null. However, the intent I sent back is null at onActivtyResult() even though I did sent an intent

Comment: could u update how to you start the activity? ex `Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, ActivityThatReturnInfo.class);` ? Do you start any other activity after that ? Rly don't understand why its null, if the `Intent i = new ......` is created properly it should not be empty

Comment: I start a camera intent in the middle of the second activity. The ending of the second activity (going back to the first activity) happens inside the `onActivityResult` of the camera intent.

Comment: Just for the sake of debug, could you not start the camera intent, put something in the variable and see how it does behave ?

Comment: whic variable are you talking about?

Comment: The one that you are waiting at the `onActivityResult`

Comment: `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);` saved my day thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Starting SecondActivity from FirstActivity**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 100);
```

**Sending data to FirstActivity from SecondActivity**

```
Intent intent= new Intent();
intent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
finish();
```

**getting result in FirstActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
            Log.e("Result",result);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Change your code to below and try once.
While sending intent from SecondActivity to FirstActivity `Intent i = getIntent();` to `Intent intent= new Intent();`

Comment: Yep just replace the `data = intent.get("data")` with `data = intent.getStringExtra("data");`

Comment: thanks, but that's not answering my question. My problem was that the result code is CANCELLED even though I sent OK. Means, it doesn't get inside the if condition

Comment: Can you explain in which scenario You r getting RESULT_CANCELED

Comment: the scenario everything works as it should be. Activity don't crash and back button not pressed

Comment: Check this link https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: Check this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android

Comment: Updated my question